# Validate wysihtml5 editor on textarea for only spaces as input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I need to add validation on wysihtml5 enabled textarea element for only blank spaces only as input.

1. When I enter only spaces into textarea console has following value:

   ```
   &nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
   ```
2. My Validation rule which is not working is:

   ```
   if (!$.trim(<textarea value>)) {
           // textarea is empty or contains only white-space
           toastr.error("You forgot to write your answer body, kindly write some thing in answer box.");               
           return false;
       }
   ```
3. I didn't get any wysihtml5 option to validate input value which is only blank spaces

   ```
   $('#some-textarea').wysihtml5({
   "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
   "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
   "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
   "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
   "link": true, //Button to insert a link. Default true
   "image": true, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
   "color": false //Button to change color of font  
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done as follows:

```
var name = $("#textAreaInput").val(); #&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
var n = name.replace(/ /g,'');
var c = n.replace(/^(&nbsp;)+/g, '');
var f = c.replace(/^(<br>)+/g, '');
if (f.length==0) {
    toastr.error("Display error");
    return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;</strong> How to Validate this text then

Answer (score 0):

For future such requirements, it is advisable to get the editor's value like this:

```
var name = $("#textAreaInput").data('wysihtml5').editor.getValue();

var validateWysi = name.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/^(&nbsp;)+/g, '').replace(/^(<br>)+/g, '').replace(/^(<br\/>)+/g, '');

if(validateWysi.length==0)
{

toastr.error("Display error");

return false;

}
```